# Find recently upvoted/downvoted comments/answers/questions?

Tags: discussion

When I see my reputation change (either go up or down), is there any way for me to find out which post/comment/answer triggered it? I'm always curious to know what people liked or disliked about what I wrote. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the envelope at the top of the page to see which posts caused reputation change.

[image]

Comment: Ohh wow, I never really got what it's for; thanks! (Another question: What does it mean when it turns yellow?)

Comment: @Mehrdad That means that there are updates in your inbox. You only need to check it when it turns yellow.

Comment: ... this sounds like a silly question, but what inbox are you referring to, and what does it do? If you're referring to the StackExchange icon at the top-left, I've seen these two turn on and off completely independently. Also, I've tried clicking the envelope when it turns yellow, but I've never been able to find out what's triggered it.

Comment: I know which envelope icon you're referring to, it's just that I don't see what you mean by "updates" being in my "inbox". What's an update (is it a notification of some sort?), and what's the inbox (what does it hold)? In which situations do I get updates in my inbox?

Comment: @Mehrdad Envelope is now reputation changes and badges; Global Inbox (top left) is new answers and comments. The theory is that you want to see answers and comments right away no matter what SE site you're on, but rep and badge changes aren't that important.

Comment: Ohhh okay, that makes sense. Thanks! :)